# EDI conversion in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, edi

I have EDI files on a file server how do I decode them into xml/json/csv in azure?

I tried using logic apps X12 using the lookup artifact of the integration account.

Comment: Easy: use an EDI translator.  Plenty out there on the market.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to convert Edi files to XML from logic apps using `Decode X12 message` of X12 Connector.

[image]

Make sure you are adding the required schemas, Map, Partners and Agreement in your Integration account before executing.

[image]

**NOTE:** To create schemas or maps you require either of the following

> - Visual Studio 2019 and the  [Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools Extension](https://aka.ms/vsenterpriseintegrationtools).
> - Visual Studio 2015 and the  [Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools for Visual Studio 2015 2.0](https://aka.ms/vsmapsandschemas)  extension.

You can refer more on [Add schemas to use with workflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-schemas?tabs=consumption#smaller-schema)

Below is the flow of my Logic App.

[image]

Comment: hanks, just one question as I jam just decoding and transforming, Do I still need Partners and Agreement? If yes, what should I put?

Comment: I am having this error ....The message has an unknown document type and did not resolve to any of the existing schemas configured in the agreement